# How to check which radio button has been selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
If (acctRB.Checked == true)

{
Execute Business Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need the `== true`:

```
if (acctRB.checked)
{
    // It's checked
} 
else 
{
    // It's not checked
}
```

So what you have is pretty much correct. Just remove the `== true` as it's not required.

Comment: if document.getElementById('acctRB').checked == true){
    alert('hi');
    }

Comment: You're missing a bracket: `if (document.getElementById('acctRB').checked){ alert('hi'); }`. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WRHAn/

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that IE is case insensitive while other browsers aren't. Your sample code will work for IE....

Rather do

```
if (acctRB.checked) {
     //Checked
} else {

  //Unchecked
}
```

It works for both IE and other major browsers....Or, if if checkbox **id** is `"acctRB"` do,

```
if (document.getElementById("acctRB").checked) {

   //Checked
} else {

   //Unchecked
}
```